# tantamount of while(cin>>something){some task ;} in java?

Tags: java, c++, while-loop, cin

I'm a beginner in java. But I know that we have some trick for take input since user add input in c++.

```
while(cin>>x)
{
  g++;
}
```

I want use from this in java ,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use either *command line arguments* or the [`Scanner` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class GetInputFromUser
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a;
        float b;
        String s;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a string");
        s = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You entered string " + s);

        System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        a = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("You entered integer " + a);

        System.out.println("Enter a float");
        b = in.nextFloat();
        System.out.println("You entered float " + b);
    }
}
```

You can put any loop in here. Search loops in java. And use this to perform what you're asking.